# Number of subsets not containing a subset of fixed cardinality

Tags: combinatorics

Let $B$ a subset of $V$ where $|V|=n$ and $1<|B|=k \le n$. How many subsets of $n-1$ elements don't contain $B$?

Moreover, I have another question. Let $B$ as before and $v \in V \setminus B$. Which is the number of $l-$subsets which don't contain neither $B$ nor $v$? And which is the number of $l-$subsets which don't contain $B$ but contain $v$ (in both questions I require $l \ge k$)? 
 Can you write a formula using binomial coefficient, please?

Comment: Don't contain or don't intersect $B$ ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to choose the one element of $V$ that is not in the subset. If you don't want it to contain $B$ that element has to belong to $B$. Hence there are $k$ such subsets.

---

Second part of the request: There are $\binom{n}{l}$ subsets of size $l$ total, there are $\binom{n-k}{l-k}$ subsets that are contained in $B$. Therefore there are $\binom{n}{l}-\binom{n-k}{l-k}$ subsets of the desired kind.

Comment: I'm sorry but I think they are $\binom{n}{n-1}-\binom{n-k}{n-k-1}=k+1$... Isn't it?

Comment: $\binom{n}{n-1}=n$ and $\binom{n-k}{n-k-1}=n-k$

Comment: Yeah, I wrote badly in my exercise book. What about the second part of my request?

Comment: Done, I hope it helps.